# Why does my simulation not support the idea that inbreeding is bad?

Tags: population-genetics, theoretical-biology

After reading [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/askscience/comments/2wkgfi/in_terms_of_genetics_why_is_inbreeding_such_a_bad/) post, I wrote some code to simulate inbreeding.

> We have a population of $N$ creatures. Each creature has two genes, which come in two forms: recessive (a) and dominant (A). The creatures' initial genomes are random. At each stage, the following happens, in order:
>
> 1. Each creature with the recessive phenotype (aa) dies with probability $p_R$.
> 2. Each creature with the dominant phenotype (AA, aA, or Aa) dies with probability $p_D<p_R$.
> 3. Each creature then decides to have children with probability $q$. Each creature that decides to have children *chooses a mate* (see below) and has three children with that mate.
>
> I wrote two different kinds of creature, incest-averse and incest-seking. Each time I ran the simulation, the population consisted of either all incest-averse or all invest-seeking creatures.
>
> 1. An incest-averse creature chooses a mate randomly and uniformly from the set of its non-siblings.
> 2. An incest-seeking creature chooses a mate randomly and uniformly from the set of its siblings. If it has no siblings, it just randomly picks anybody.

In practice, since each union produces 3 children, the incest-seeking creatures almost never fail to have siblings after a few generations.

What I found was that whichever type of creature I used, the results were the same: the frequency of the *aa* genotype plummeted to almost zero. I used the parameters $N=100$, $p_R=0.1$ $p_D=0.05$ $q=0.022$.

Presumably my model is in some way too simple. What am I not taking into account?

[Source code](https://pastebin.com/LMSv2RrL)

Comment: Your question title does not really fit your post. Your simulations **do show that inbreeding is bad since the recessive genotype frequency drops to very low non-zero values in your inbreeding scenario**, which is expected under high dominance coefficients. What does not fit your expectations is your null model: the outcome of the *non-inbreeding* scenario. The main problem seems to be that there is no differential fitness effect for recessive genotypes: if *all* recessive genotypes have such a strong negative fitness effect, you do not have power to separate your two models.

Comment: @AlexDeLarge From the reddit post I linked to, my interpretation was that reducing the frequency of *aa* is what we want (since that phenotype is less fit). In that case, what do we actually expect to happen under non-inbreeding, and why is it a "good" thing?

Comment: I notice your simulation doesn't actually compare the spread of phenotypes of "incest-seeking" and "incest-avoiding", you just prescribe one or the other. What your simulation shows is that deleterious phenotypes tend to go extinct, which is what we would expect, incest or no incest (if anything it might happen faster with incest because the deleterious allele is less likely to "hide behind" the non-deleterious one; see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_purging). I think the question is, what does "incest is bad" mean to you and how did you expect this simulation to show it?

Comment: Given your setting you expect to have **low frequency of recessive homozygotes even without inbreeding**. But in reality, recessive homozygous genotypes do not need to be deleterious, in fact only a small fraction is. Accordingly, given that recessive deleterious alleles are very rare and most often found in healthy heterozygous carriers, they are rarely combined by chance. The problem with your simulation is that it does not capture that inbreeding, due to excess homozyogotes, strongly increases that probability as you penalise every homozygous recessive genotype.

Comment: @RozennKeribin I was trying to understand why inbreeding is considered "bad", genetically. From the reddit post I linked, I thought the idea was that with inbreeding, deleterious alleles go extinct less quickly, although in retrospect that doesn't make much sense. If that's a mistake, then "Why is inbreeding bad?" should be taken to be part of the question.

Comment: inbreeding is bad becasue it prevents variety in genotype, the very thing sex evolved to produce. Sex itself is costly and time consuming so doing away with it's benefit but keeping the sex is counterproductive.

Comment: With inbreeding, you have a good chance of both parents sharing the same very deleterious mutations, which means their kids are likely to be homozygous for those mutations.  Make your sim have dozens of genes, crank up the penalties for being homozygous, and see what your populations numbers look like in the incestuous group.

Comment: I also wonder if your "sibs, then breed randomly" is going to result in a lot of outbreeding once the genetic load of deleterious mutations gets bad, and you get a lot of only children.  If you could change the sim so that singletons try to mate with cousins when there are no sibs, instead of randomly, then you'll have more inbreeding in your inbreeding population.

Comment: @Jack M "If that's a mistake, then "Why is inbreeding bad?" should be taken to be part of the question" -> it is a mistake, but given it changes the tenor of your question you might want to edit it taking the new info into account. For why inbreeding is "bad", you might want to try simulations that compare inbreeding vs outbreeding phenotypes (in the long run deleterious alleles go extinct either way, but in the meantime the inbreeders might see less-fit offspring than the outbreeders and be selected against) and asexual vs sexual reproduction (because inbreeding makes sex more like asex)

Comment: Try using nonlethal recessive alleles such as those involved in color blindness, then consider the frequency of color blindness on the two groups.

Comment: @JeppeNielsen If the alleles have no effect on death rates, then you end up with roughly 25% of each genotype no matter what. This is pretty obvious when you think about it because all four genotypes are entirely equivalent as far as the simulation is concerned.

Comment: You do certainly not get 25% of each genotype unless that is your starting frequency. Consider the case were the "a" allele have a frequency of 1% in the general population. Assume that the Hardy-Weinberg principle ( https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardy-Weinberg_principle) is in effect and calculate the equilibrium frequencies. Next consider the situation were inbreeding is occuring, then it should be quite clear that inbreeding increases the frequency of rare recessive allels.